# How to combine two variables in JavaScript into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, chatbot

I am trying to concatenate two variables in order to emit both boxes of a form (initials & message) to my chatbot server and have them show up in the browser.

`````
  var text = $('#message').val(); 
  var initials =$('#initials').val();
//I need to combine the two above variables so I can emit one distinct variable
  socket.emit('message', text);
  $('#message').val('');
  $('#initials').val('');
  return false;
});

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
  $('<li>').text(msg).appendTo('#history');
});````
`````

Comment: Use the + operator?

Comment: Alternatively .concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either join them from the values of the input before the call to the emit, join them IN the call to the emit or in the method on the socket (after the emit) as an extra argument

```
  var text = $('#message').val() + $('#initials').val();
  ...
  socket.emit('message', text);
```

or simply join as arguments

```
...
  socket.emit('message', text + initials);
...
```

or leave them separate and add the initials as an extra argument

```
...
  socket.emit('message', text, initials);

....
socket.on('message', function (msg, initials) {
  $('<li>').text(msg + initials).appendTo('#history');
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with operator '+':

```
socket.emit('message', text + initials);
```